# turn a matrix into a sorted list google docs/spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, matrix, google-sheets

I've created a large-ish matrix by doing a =pearson( analysis on survey responses in google docs/spreadsheets and would like to convert it into a sorted list.

The matrix has labels (the survey questions) in row 2 and column b. Each intersecting cell has the value. Here's what the formula looks like.

=pearson(FILTER( Pc!$C$2:$AW$999 ; Pc!$C$2:$AW$2= C$2 ),FILTER(Pc!$C$2:$AW$999 ;Pc!$C$2:$AW$2=$B3))

This is what I'd like to get to:

```
      a                   b                  c
Question one       question 2            correlation
```

Then sorting by column c is easy.

How can I get all the points out of the matrix/array, along with the labels in this way?

Ideally I'd be able to do this only to points below the diagonal as there of course are dupes above..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet as "view only", so I can take a look at a sample of the data to understand it better? (e.g. if you don't want to, please create a spreadsheet with bogus data and the same structure)

Comment: Sure, here's a link. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhESHlfBQRFGdDM3cU9maURWakhiN3VHYzNnVGU0N0E)

Comment: Will this generate one row for each value under the diagonal? i.e. the combination of all questions against all others? Isn't this table arrangement better to look and find results?

Comment: Such formula is too difficult for me to come up without spending long hours thinking about it. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for the look. yes the idea was to simply rank them by correlation, what you want is simply to know where the strongest links are. I'm thinking you'd have to do it in several steps with fancy indirects but still not sure how to get them all into a single array.. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to placing the combination of the headers in a single column.
It involves a series of auxiliary columns, but works.

Let's say we have a single column with all unique headers on column `A`. I'll assume it's 6 values. So, on cell `B1` we paste:

```
=ArrayFormula(join(";";A1&","&A2:A$6))
```

And then copy it down to `B5`. On `C1` we join it all and split making a single column:

```
=transpose(split(join(";";B1:B5);";"))
```

If needed, we can split the combination in two columns again on `D1`

```
=ArrayFormula(split(C1:C15;","))
```

I don't know why, but the value on `E1` does not work correctly, so I just pasted `=A2`

With these columns you can easily do your nice `Pearson-Filter` trick again to have it all in a single column. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. I'm woring out the kinks, will let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will help:

=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(CONCATENATE(transpose(C2:AW999)&char(9)), char(9))))

(C2:AW999 is your data range)